# How to find a key's value from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, find

How do I get a given key's value from a list of dictionaries?

```
mylist = [
    {
      'powerpoint_color': 'blue',
      'client_name': 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'
    },
    {
      'sort_order': 'ascending',
      'chart_layout': '1',
      'chart_type': 'bar'
    }
]
```

The number of dictionaries in `mylist` is unknown and I want to find the value attached to the key `'sort_order'`.

My failed attempt:

```
for key in mylist:
    for value in key:
        print(key['sort_order'])
```

Comment: @Chris Adams - thanks for cleaning my list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mylist= [{'powerpoint_color': 'blue', 'client_name': 'Sport Parents (Regrouped)'}, {'sort_order': 'ascending', 'chart_layout': '1', 'chart_type': 'bar'}]

print [d["sort_order"] for d in mylist if "sort_order" in d][0]
```

Result:

```
ascending
```

---

You could also combine all of the dictionaries into a single dict, and access that:

```
combined_d = {key: value for d in mylist for key,value in d.iteritems() }
print combined_d["sort_order"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it using this code:

```
for d in mylist:
    if 'sort_order' in d:
        print(d['sort_order'])
```

First you iterate over list, for each dictionary check if it has needed key and if it does get value.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I can see where I went wrong now. I will use the list comprehension method but give this an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
for hash in mylist:
    if "sort_order" in hash: print hash ["sort_order"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While not as readable, this version:

- provides short-circuiting
- avoids a double lookup

---

```
print reduce( lambda a,b: a or b, (l.get("sort_order") for l in mylist) )
```

Note that this would fail if some of your keys evaluated to false, but it's not hard to develop a version that doesn't from this starting point