# how to search inside dictionaries wrapped in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

We have many dict in a list

for example:

```
    list=[
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Sara", "age": 11},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

how can I search for "ar" characters in "name" ( or any other character sequences)?
I mean how can I retrieve only "name" with "ar"
in other words, how can I search inside dict in list in python?

Comment: A for loop + an if should do.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783217/find-a-keys-value-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-python

Comment: don't need a loop either. can just use a `list` comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You may use `if <substring> in <string>` like `if "ar" in "Sara"`

Implying to your example:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if "ar" in list[i]["name"]:
        # here you are
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's string `.find` method:

```
list=[
   {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
   {"name": "Sara", "age": 11},
   {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
   {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]

stringToFind = "ar"

for dic in list:
    if dic.keys()[0].find(stringToFind) !== -1:
        #dict key contains the "ar" string
    else:
        #dict key does not contain the "ar" string
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough:

```py
listy_list = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
  {"name": "Sara", "age": 11},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]

res = [mappy for mappy in listy_list if 'ar' in mappy['name']]

res
# [{'name': 'Sara', 'age': 11}, {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 5}]
```